# How to convert com.hierynomus.sbmj.share.File to Base64 String?

Tags: base64, smb, smbj

Using Java 1.8 and SMBJ 0.11.5

Trying to read file from Network share using..

> File remoteFile = networkShare.openFile(..);
> https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.hierynomus/smbj/latest/com/hierynomus/smbj/share/DiskShare.html#openFile(java.lang.String,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateDisposition,java.util.Set)

com.hierynomus.sbmj.share.File (from network share folder) to Base64 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used apache.commons.io library

`java.io.InputStream is = smbFileDownload.getInputStream(); byte[] bytes1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(is); byte[] byte64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes1); String bass64Str = (new String(byte64));`